# Cloudformation: How to append properties to a pre-defined bucket?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a template which defines an s3 bucket. I cannot modify the template. I am only allowed to add extra information to the template. 
How can I add encryption to that pre-defined s3 bucket?

```
Resources:
    s3Bucket:
        Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
        Properties:
            BucketName: "my pre-defined bucket"
    # I want to write something like below code. I can get a reference of the pre-defined bucket then add encryption
    s3BucketEncryption:
        Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
        Properties:
            BucketName: !Ref s3Bucket  
            BucketEncryption: 
              ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
               - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                 SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe make a copy of the template and modify the original bucket?

Comment: It is not possible to do what you show. Such properties need to be defined when the bucket is created, not in a separate operation. It sounds very strange that you can "add extra information to the template" and yet you cannot "modify" the template. Can you tell us more about the restrictions under which you are operating?

Comment: our project import a template A from outside, the bucket defined in template A. I am allowed to add new customized templates to our project and the project will merge template A with my customized templates. I need to add encryption to the bucket defined in template A.

Answer (score 0):

You can [import existing resources into CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/) now. This allows you to bring control of the bucket created outside of CloudFormation into it, and thereby allows you to change its properties.